# Getting fonts, sizes, bold,...etc

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm having trouble finding stuff on accessing Windows fonts or predefined fonts, and sizes. So for my java program I have a `JComboBox` with fonts, sizes, and colors. The problem is that I need to pre-Enter the fonts, sizes and colors. How would I be able to get the predefined fonts, colors, and sizes? So far this is what I have for this font but its not in the correct way.

```
               if (font.equals("Arial")) {

                if (size.equals("8")) {
                    setSize = 8;
                } else if (size.equals("10")) {
                    setSize = 10;
                } else if (size.equals("12")) {
                    setSize = 12;
                }

                if (color.equals("Black")) {
                    setColor = Color.BLACK;
                } else if (color.equals("Blue")) {
                    setColor = Color.BLUE;
                } else if (color.equals("Red")) {
                    setColor = Color.red;
                }

                Font font = new Font("Arial", setAttribute, setSize);
                Writer.setFont(font);
                Writer.setForeground(setColor);
```

Comment: *"i'm having trouble finding stuff on accessing windows fonts or predefined fonts"*  You would have trouble finding that for Mac. and *nix boxes.  Why code in Java if targeting only Windows?

Comment: Its just an exercise that someone told me to do, not a full scale application just trying to learn some stuff

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

The sizes and styles can be set at run-time.

### E.G.

[image: Font Chooser]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShowFonts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            String[] fonts = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
            JComboBox fontChooser = new JComboBox(fonts);
            fontChooser.setRenderer(new FontCellRenderer());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fontChooser);
        });
    }
}

class FontCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
        Font font = new Font(value.toString(), Font.PLAIN, 20);
        label.setFont(font);
        return label;
    }
}
```

### JavaDoc

The JDoc for [`GraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames--) state in part..

> Returns an array containing the names of all font families in this `GraphicsEnvironment` localized for the default locale, as returned by `Locale.getDefault()`..

> #### See also:
>
> [`getAllFonts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts--)..

Comment: Wow, this was exactly what I was looking for. So GraphicsEnvironment gets the types of fonts that your system is running on?