# Find out what actual font used for Java font

Tags: java, fonts

I create a font object in Java using

```java
new Font("Arial, Helvetica, Helv", 1, 10);
```

Neither Arial nor Helvetica is installed on my computer. How do I find out what actual font gets used? Does OpenJDK have it's own fonts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get system default font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140248/get-system-default-font)

Answer (score 0):

As I know OpenJDK is not shipped with font like Oracle JDK, so very likely you are loading your font from your operating system.

Are you sure what is being displayed is "Arial, Helvetica, Helv"? Base on Java [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)), if the font cannot be found, Java will try to load the closer font family/face, or proceed with some algorithm to achieve the desired style. You can check the link to read more.