# Change font of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel

how to change Font of JLabel ?
I try this but with no succes:

```
JLabel nadpis = new JLabel(); 
nadpis.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 100)); 
nadpis.setText("hi");
```

Just size is changed but Font is still same

Comment: Is Papyrus available on your system? Is it spelled and capitalized correctly?

Comment: For the available fonts, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149).

Comment: yea you are right I didnt see papyrus in my available fonts. How can I add it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I didn't see papyrus in my available fonts.  How can I add it?

Look in the [`Font` methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#method_summary) for the `createFont()` variants.