# Is there a way to list all directories from which fonts are loaded in java?

Tags: java, fonts

I am using iText to generate PDF files, which may include embedded fonts. iText includes a `DefaultFontMapper` class which allows us to specify a directory from which to load fonts that may then be embedded in the generated PDF files as needed. The program itself is run across a range of environments (Windows, Linux, Solaris...) and manually specifying directories has resulted in errors in the past (Due to directories being omitted).

My question is, "Is there a way in java to get all the directories from which fonts are loaded?"

Comment: See my answer below - unfortunaltely only a partial solution, good question though, +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is only possible to list fontNames that are currently used (can be tricky due to `GraphicsEnvironment` being used on headless environment)

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

Comment: I guess I am trying to get a something that the API designers were deliberately trying to abstract away. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149).

Comment: Listing fonts is fairly easy - unfortunately fonts do not include info on the file from which they were loaded, so there does not seem to be a simple way to do this. I ended up setting a configuration file which may be used to specify additional font directories - not perfect, but it will have to do for now