# JTextFields automatically resizing

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am making a program that is supposed to allow you to type in text, and it will that text in every single font on the computer. Here is a screenshot of what happens just as the fonts are loaded:
[image: A screenshot]
Now, I realize that there are a billion other problems besides the automatic resizing of the JTextFields, but I want to focus on one thing at a time. Anyway, whenenver I scroll down in the JScrollPane, here's what happens: 
[image: A screenshot]
Could someone please tell me what I have to do with the GridBagConstraints or the JTextFields to fix this problem? Here's a bit of code, hope it helps -

```
 gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 5, 2, 5);
 gbc.gridx = 0;
 gbc.gridwidth = gbc.gridheight = 1;
 gbc.weightx = gbc.weighty = 1;
 gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` to encourage the components to use the available horizontal space.

A better solution would be to use a `JList`.

I would add each `Font` to a `ListModel` and using the master text, allow a `ListCellRenderer` to render it.

But that's me

Comment: "But that's me" Nay, I think that's a lot of people

Comment: See also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149) using a combo-box for the font list.  It customizes a `DefaultListCellRenderer` into a `FontCellRenderer`.