# Applet not displaying an array of strings

Tags: java, fonts, applet, awt

i want to print the contents of an array of strings inside an applet as a list, but nothing appears when the applet starts, only something appears and it seems to be the strings inside the array but they need a space between each other, here's the applet:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FontApplet extends Applet{
String[] fonts;

public void init() {

fonts =GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();


}
public void update(Graphics g){paint(g);}
public void paint(Graphics g) {

for(String str:fonts)
     g.drawString(str, 100, 125);
   }
  }
```

Comment: 1) It is the 3rd millennium, time to use `JApplet` & Swing in general.  2) Given this is related to fonts, see [`FontCellRenderer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965149/418556) - use that in a `JComboBox` or `JList` for a nicely rendered (and spaced!) list of available fonts.  I suspect those algorithms for padding (e.g. in the accepted answer) will go off-screen before about 'd' in the font list. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int x = 100;
for(String str:fonts)
 g.drawString(str, x, 125);
 x += 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing them all at location (100, 125).