# Filling a combo box with list of available fonts, Java

Tags: java, swing, list, fonts, jcombobox

How would I use the GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts() method to populate a combo box with a list of all available fonts?

---

I used

```
JComboBox font = new 
    JComboBox(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts());
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: This should be very do-able with minimal effort -- what have you tried?

Comment: I'm sort of new to all of this, so I'm not sure where to start, I've though about using an enhanced for loop, but honestly I don't know how that would work.

Comment: 1) look at the combo box tutorial to see how to use them. 2) Look at the GraphicsEnvironment API to see what `getAllFonts()` returns. 3) After doing this, I think you can accomplish your task in 3-4 lines of code or less, but at least please first give it a try.

Comment: I used
        'JComboBox font = new JComboBox(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts());'

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965149/418556) for a superior implementation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Frickin' show-off! :) 1+. 100+ if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding,

> I used JComboBox font = new JComboBox(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts());
>   That hasn't worked.

It does work. But you have to set the list cell renderer to display the font name. For example,

```
GraphicsEnvironment graphEnviron = 
       GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Font[] allFonts = graphEnviron.getAllFonts();

JComboBox<Font> fontBox = new JComboBox<>(allFonts);
fontBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
         Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      if (value != null) {
         Font font = (Font) value;
         value = font.getName();
      }
      return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
            isSelected, cellHasFocus);
   }
});
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(fontBox));
```

This is all well described in the [combo box tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).