# Can't change font using JComboBox

Tags: java

I am trying to change font of my JTextField by using a JComboBox. The problem is when I try to run the program it works fine but now when I try to change font in the program I get tons of errors. Here is the code:

```
    JTextField myJTextField = new JTextField ("This text will be changed!", 20);
    myJTextField.setEditable(false);
    add(myJTextField);

    Font font = new Font ("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    Font font1 = new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
    Font font2 = new Font ("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
    Font myFonts [] = {font ,font1, font2};
    myBox1 = new JComboBox (myFonts);

    myBox1.addItemListener (new ItemListener () {
        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e) {
            Font myFonts [] = {font ,font1, font2};
            int array [] = {0,1,2};

            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    myFonts [0] = new Font ("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
            else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    myFonts [1] = new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
            else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    myFonts [2] = new Font ("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);

            myJTextField.setFont(myFonts[array.length]);
        }
    }); add(myBox1);
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you get tons of errors and need our help, it makes sense for you to post some of them, no? Please read the [help] section for more help on asking a good question. Also, consider taking a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as that would help us better understand your problem.

Comment: `myJTextField.setFont(myFonts[array.length]);` Can't do that since that will give you Index Out Of Bounds  Since the length of array is the same length as myFonts and Arrays are zero-based index in Java

Answer (score 1):

If I am not erring, every if condition the same. And `myFonts[array.length]` will yield an IndexOutOf Bounds.

```
myBox1.addItemListener (new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Font font = (Font) e.getItem();
            myJTextField.setFont(font);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `Font` objects directly into a JComboBox constructor. Look into using `setRenderer()` and creating your own Renderer class like this example:

[Getting fonts, sizes, bold,...etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149)