# Why is my Swing app not displaying properly?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I'm trying to come up with a Swing app that can display all available fonts and show me how they look :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo_Fonts extends JPanel
{
  static String[] font_type;
//  int[] styles={Font.PLAIN,Font.ITALIC,Font.BOLD,Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD};
  int[] styles={Font.PLAIN};
  String[] stylenames={"Plain","Italic","Bold","Bold & Italic"};

  Demo_Fonts()
  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,3000));
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    for (int f=0;f<font_type.length;f++)
    {
      for (int s=0;s<styles.length;s++)
      {
        Font font=new Font(font_type[f],styles[s],18);
        g.setFont(font);
        String name=font_type[f]+" "+stylenames[s];
//        g.drawString(name,20,(f*4+s+1)*20);
        g.drawString(name,20,(f+s+1)*20);
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] a)
  {
    font_type=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    for (int i=0;i<font_type.length;i++) System.out.println(font_type[i]);

    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(0); } });

    JScrollPane areaScrollPane=new JScrollPane(new Demo_Fonts());
    areaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    areaScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
//    areaScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600,500));
    areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,1400));
    f.setContentPane(areaScrollPane);
    f.setSize(600,1400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

But when I scroll down, the content is all messed up, why, and how to fix ?

Comment: JPanel + paintComponent, paintComponent + super.paintComponent as 1st code line, override getPreferredSize insted of setPreferredSize, f.pack() by replacing f.setSize(600,1400);

Comment: Maybe better than painting, go with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965149/2587435)

Comment: *"display all available fonts and show me how they look "*  Tip:  Use a list or [combo. to display them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965149/418556)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably Your first line of paint should probably be `super.paint(g)`. The parent `paint()` method will clear the panel.

When you scroll down, you `paint` on the component again. If you do not clear what you've already drawn, you'll just keep painting ontop of other stuff, leading to a mess.

Edit: I added this line and it works on my computer now.

Edit: As mKorbel suggests, you should really be overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint`. `paint` is more for AWT, but it "works" for your program. If you work with Java Swing, you generally override `paintComponent`. So really, you should delete you `paint` method and replace it with

```
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
      super.paintComponent( g );
    for (int f=0;f<font_type.length;f++)
    {
      for (int s=0;s<styles.length;s++)
      {
        Font font=new Font(font_type[f],styles[s],18);
        g.setFont(font);
        String name=font_type[f]+" "+stylenames[s];
//        g.drawString(name,20,(f*4+s+1)*20);
        g.drawString(name,20,(f+s+1)*20);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: please to change paint to the paintComponent, then very good answer

Comment: @mKorbel I have put it in as a suggestion.