# JComboBox with a label that applies a different value/data type behind the scenes?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How do I have a `JComboBox` with a label viewable to the end user that applies a different value/data type behind the scenes?

I've built a basic calculator for my workplace. It calculates finished roll size and diameter based on length, material thickness, and core size. If I use all text fields and stick to int/double data types it's easy and works well. However dealing with sales people etc., that do not know material thicknesses, I want to switch to a combo box for those entries.

For example I want the first combo box item to say "Thermal transfer Permanent" but I want the thickness value of .005 to be entered into my math behind the scenes, and my second item would be "Thermal Direct Permanent" but I want .006 to be entered into my math. There are many more materials and thicknesses that will be added.

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, define a class that encapsulates the information related to these combo. entries & use those objects as a basis for the combo. Then see [How to Use Combo Boxes: Providing a Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for making them pretty. Here is [an example using font families](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149) (it probably should have used `Font` objects rather than `String` objects of the `Font` family name, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JComboBox` can display list of any objects. The text it displays is (usually) text returned by the `toString()` method of said objects. All you need to do is to create your own data object that holds the label and the value.

Like this:

```
class CoBoItem {
    private final String display;
    private final float value;

    // constructor to create your data objects
    CoBoItem(String display, float value) {
        this.display = display;
        this.value = value;
    }
    // methods to get the values
    String getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    float getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    // this will be displayed in the JComboBox
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return display;
    }
}
```

Then initialize your JComboBox with this data class as type parameter, like this.

```
JComboBox<CoBoItem> cb = new JComboBox<>();
cb.addItem(new CoBoItem("Thermal transfer Permanent", 0.005f));
cb.addItem(new CoBoItem("Thermal Direct Permanent", 0.006f));
```

You can access the selected item with

```
cb.getSelectedItem();
```

it will return an Object so you will have to cast it into your CoBoItem.